# Trying to display multiple php files at once, in a row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, get

I currently have a page that displays invoices for printing.  I would like to create a page where I can feed in multiple invoices, so that I can print multiple invoices.  Of course, I could just copy the code and loop it in the new file, but I thought it might be easier to just call the other pages and assemble them on a page.  I saw some code similar to this, and tried to modify it, but I keep getting an error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Maybe there is a way to do this only in php?

I post an array of invoices to this php file:

```
<?php
$invoiceList = $_POST["invoiceRequest"];
$invoices = explode("\n", $invoiceList);
echo '<html>';
    echo '</head>';
        echo '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo '$(document).ready(function(){';
            foreach($invoices as $page) {
                echo "$.get('ajax/invoices/invoicePrint.php?invoiceId=".$page."').success(function(html) {
                    $('#page".$page."').html(html);
                });";
            }
        echo '});';
        echo '</script>';
    echo '</head>';
    echo '<body>';
        foreach($invoices as $page) {
            echo '<div id = "page'.$page.'"></div>';
        }
    echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
?>
```

Comment: The reason is that each `$page` inside loop has `\r` left as you explode only by `\n`. Expolde by `\r\n`, or add this inside your *foreach* loops: `preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~','',$page)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exploding` post data by `\n` may leave some unwanted chars in array values (like `\r`, which will be interpreted as new line too and cause that `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error). To answer this particular question, I would suggest you to [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the values.

You could also improve your actual code a bit by making it shorter and more clear.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".invoice").each(function(){
                    $(this).load("ajax/invoices/invoicePrint.php?invoiceId="+$(this).data('invoiceid'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php foreach(explode("\n", $_POST["invoiceRequest"]) as $page): ?>
        <div data-invoiceid="<?php echo trim($page); ?>" class="invoice"></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I was super confused why that was happening.  This code works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL to fetch the document instead of ajax
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply use file_get contents

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

echo file_get_contents('ajax/invoices/invoicePrint.php?invoiceId='.$page);